# How can I create a data structure starting at a specified memory address (without using new)?

Tags: c++, data-structures, new-operator, allocation

I asked a similar question before, but I only realized now that the answer I received isn't totally what I wanted.

If I simply have a pointer of some structure type, how can I either move to, or create an instance of the same structure type starting at an address specified by the struct pointer (which I have assigned an address to) without using "new".

Comment: Is this C or C++, the answer to the (for me confusing) question surely depends on the language --in C everything is a POD type (as defined in the C++ standard), while in C++ you could be talking about non-PODs.

Comment: C++. I will not be using classes, only structs, if that applies.

Comment: I have removed the C tag as you have defined that you are using C++.

Comment: @MHZ: In C++, the difference between `struct` and `class` is only that the default access specifier is `public` for `struct` and `private` for `class`. In particular, given `struct base { virtual void foo() {} }`, you cannot work with an object of type `base` without initializing it, and for that you need *placement new*. On the other hand, you could use `class another { int x; public: int& getX() { return x; } }` without calling the constructor (which is *trivial* in this case)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I would like to create a linked list of 255 structures of 256 bytes in a single segment utilizing a segment and offset address, utilizing far pointers. Because I want a particular structure to exist at some address (0x5000), and then another structure 256 bytes ahead (in terms of address), then I would want to simply add an offset to a segment address and instantiate the structure at that address (Ex. one struct at 0x50000, another at 0x500FF. However, there were many things that I didn't understand in terms of how this is done.

Comment: @MHZ: I have to say, I pity you. Segments and near/far pointers have been gone for 15 years, and your compiler is so old, it's pre-Standard. That's bad.

Comment: haha, I guess it's part of the learning experience. But thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what placement `new` is for:

```
foo* p = new(0x9000) foo(bar);
```

Comment: Note that this is the correct answer- if you have that memory already. You can't allocate memory at an arbitrary address.

Comment: I am a little bit confused with something here. If I wanted to create my data at 0x9000, where would I assign that address to in this statement? You are assigning an address to a pointer in this statement, while I am looking to create data at the address specified by a pointer.

Comment: @MHZ: If you want to create data at a specific address, *you're doing it wrong*. If you absolutely must, then you will have to look into platform-specific allocation routines and allocating yourself, as C++ does not offer any way to specify addresses of allocated memory.

Comment: @MHZ: Also note that 0x9000 as seen in the code, will be an address relative to the address space of the process, not necessarily the byte at position 0x9000 in the actual hardware. As @DeadMG points out, you will have to use platform-specific code to deal with exact addresses, and in most cases the request for a pointer at hardware address 0x9000, will result in a pointer that has a different address in your process (i.e. printing the value of the pointer will most probably not yield the same number)

Comment: Ahh. Good to know. I'm using far pointers with the Borland 4.5 IDE & compiler for this assignment, but you've cleared up a lot of info for me. Thank you!

Comment: @MHZ: Why are you using a compiler that's at least 15 years old??

Comment: @MHZ: Far pointers were already obsolescent in 1995 or so. Are you a time traveler?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions

1. Use placement new instead of new.
2. For a C style structure simply copy the structure to the memory address and typecast it - bitwise copy

   i.e.

   ```
   CreateStructAtAddr(void* pOutput, mystruct* pInput)
   {
       *(mystruct*)pOutput = *pInput;
   }
   ```

I am ignoring check for valid memory for brevity

Comment: I have downvoted this because you did not construct an instance of mystruct before assigning to it, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what would I assign the desired address to in this statement? Could I use void* pOutput = 0x9000 initially (for example)?

Comment: @MHZ: No- you're reading/writing into memory you haven't allocated. If you need a specific pre-determined address, then you must look into your OS allocation routines to allocate it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation DeadMG. To clarify, I'm doing this for a university assignment to become familiar with segmentation and the x86 architecture. My prof would like for me to avoid using memalloc, but yet be able to refer to offset segment addresses for memory blocks that I allocated myself. However, I can't create these structs at the offset due to the inability to physically assign an address.

Comment: @MHZ: x86-32 and x86-64 has a virtual flat memory model, not segmentation. If you want to learn about segmentation, you will need an x86-16 processor. More importantly, there is no way to allocate memory that isn't on the stack without using an OS or library allocation routine.

Comment: @DeadMG "The assumption here is that valid pointers are getting passed to the structure. The caller has pointer to the structure being duplicated and pointer to memory where it needs to be copied. The reason I used function to this job because then its easy to replace this by placement new without impacting all the locations where it is being used.
So please reconsider your downvote or explain your reasoning in detail

Comment: @Neera: This isn't about the validity of the memory. You did not construct an instance of mystruct before assigning to it- that is, you are assigning to an uninitialized instance. That is undefined behaviour unless the type is POD, which the OP did not specify as a constraint.

Comment: @DeadMG - Thanks for clarifying . My solution was based on structs and C, I see that the question has been retagged later and classified as C++.

Comment: @Neera: It is unfortunate- I don't know why the OP tagged it C when he was using C++, as from memory that would be entirely valid C code. Perhaps you should delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering only C, where there is no constructors, once you have a pointer to a block of memory that is at least as big as the struct, then just casting that pointer to the appropriate type is sufficient.

If you are talking about C++, then it depends on the actual type. Whether it is spelled as `struct` or `class` does not make a real difference here. If the type has a *trivial constructor* then you can use the same approach than in C, as the constructor  will effectively do nothing at all. If the object has a non-trivial constructor, then you *need* to call the constructor, and that has to be done with placement new.

Comment: I was actually wondering if there was an alternative method to dynamically create the memory without using a memalloc initially. My lack of understanding comes from how the compiler assigns an address to the instance of any data type, int for example, and how that address can be hardcoded.

Comment: That is not standard, but rather OS dependent. The standard defines how to allocate memory in a portable way, but that does not allow you to define *where* you want the data to be. If you need to access some specific portion of your system's memory you will have to resort to the OS.

Answer (score -1):

Okay. Let's say you have a structure of Type A.

```
A a;
A b;
```

If you want to copy b to a (i.e. to the address of a), you would use memcpy.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/.
This would make the content of "b" start at the adress of a, given by `&a`.

If you have tow different structure types, ensure that both have the same size or you have unexpected behaviour.

Comment: `memcpy()` will invoke undefined behavior (and usually fail spectacularly) as soon as the struct contains anything but PODs. Note that this includes, for example, `std::string`.